# What free tools or techniques exist to discover anomalies in network flows?

Tags: network, intrusion, monitoring

I have been using [FlowMatrix](http://www.akmalabs.com/flowmatrix.php).  What do others do on the cheap?

Comment: I was thinking more of tools to analyze netflow traffic, I guess saying "network flows" made the question ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSSIM has an Anomalies tab that uses Ntop and can be configured with similar data.

When I did this stuff in the past, I used Ourmon.

Answer (score 6):

[WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a free tool you can use to monitor network traffic. Excellent tool to see if a hidden keylogger is trying to email and /or FTP logs because it usually has the address and password in the wireshark log.

Comment: Given that the logs are not encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

I just saw a talk at Shmoocon about the [YaF and SiLK](http://tools.netsa.cert.org/) tools that looked really good.  YaF is a flow collector (which can collect other interesting data as well), and SiLK is an analysis package for them.  There's even a nice GUI called iSiLK.